# How can i add $ symbol to inline script tag on Sharepoint Designer?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I am creating page with Sharepoint Designer 2010. I write script tag , but it underlined the $ symbol.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$('#navbarNavDropdown > ul li a').click(function(e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.parent().siblings().removeClass('active').end().addClass('active');
    e.preventDefault();
});


</script>
```

Comment: Are you directly editing the .aspx page?

Answer (score 0):

The symbol `$` is associated with jQuery, which SharePoint 2010 does not load by default. You will need to load jQuery before this script tag. Something like this:

`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>`

Just for testing -- then I suggest you pull jQuery into a library and reference it from SharePoint.